# SFX General Libraries

Tags: sfx, sound-design

What libraries would you recommend to a new audio start up as a good general base library?  I was thinking Sonopedia or Soundstorm. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in the Soundstrom library, it is reduced now for a short time: https://www.soundeffects.ch/sound-libraries/sounddogs-sound-libraries/soundstorm-motion-picture-sound-library.php

Both of them are great libraries, Soundstorm contains a bit more of background and atmosphere tracks while Sonopedia has the newer/fresher sounds. The great thing about a large sound library: If you search something, in most cases you don't find exactly what you want, but you find enough similar results to create what you want. In some cases, you find exactly what you want.
This is the advantage of a large general sound library to find a basic range of sounds for a fluent editing-workflow and not spending a lot of times for searching. But it's a matter or price and taste. Both libraries are lifetime investments. And: some of the libraries are lifework.
And please also respect to the end-user license agreement, which allows you to use the libraries for one single user. for more users, for most of the libraries you need a multiuser license.

You can browse Soundstorms online index here: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundstorm_sfx.php?SelectCategory=Air

and Sonopedias here: https://www.soundeffects.ch/sound-libraries/bwfx-sound-libraries/bw_sonopedia_sfx.php?SelectCategory=AMBIENCE

contact me if you have any question

best

guido

Answer (score 1):

To add to what's been mentioned above:

Go check out [thesoundcollectorsclub.com](http://thesoundcollectorsclub.com/).  It's a nominal fee (£20.00GBP) and it requires you to contribute to each theme, but once you get access to a few of the libraries you'll find yourself very very covered with regards to bgfx type things.

Its not broad enough to be a base library, but its an excellent and continually updated complimentary bgfx one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good if you have ready cash. Other than the Foley SFX, I actually pass Sonopedia's collection while working because it seems to have a bit of a darker under-tow with the sound designed SFX and ambiences. This is purely my preference. I do think it is a great library and  have recommended friends starting out to buy it.

For a more budget friendly approach:

Started off with a monthly subscription to the now defunct Sonomic.com. I reckon tho, if you go down that route, to buy the library you often use after a year, else what you pay for just becomes expensive.

I also managed to survive with the free sfx library that came with Logic Studio for a while before I started buying a mishmash of stuff. It covers a decent base that you will need.

Digital Juice's SFX IV is pretty comprehensive and not too bad for its price. I paid $19 for it and didn't used it because I didn't like it's search engine. Recently tho, I've taken quite a number of sounds from it for a kids drama.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the Soundstorm library, but I can comment on Sonopedia/Blastdrive. Sonopedia is a great overall library, but I do sometimes find that it lacks in terms of variations/multiple cuts. I've always been surprised that Ric didn't include more variations in some of his sound files. The library will cover most of your basic needs though, and there are a ton of "designed" effects or constructed sequences...plenty of production elements/stingers too.

You may want to look into the [Hyrbid Library](http://www.prosoundeffects.com/hybrid-sound-effects-library.html) that Pro Sound Effects offers (it's about the same cost). I did a review of it for DS, and the other libraries included fill out the few deficiencies in the Sonopedia/Blastdrive that occasionally drive me nuts. You or Steve can always e-mail me if you want any additional impressions of either library.